# IF OR with Formula Array

Tags: google-sheets

Could someone explain why

```
=arrayformula((IF(OR(I2 = "in progress"), S2+30,I2)))
```

is not working? I have look around for a solution but can't seem to quite nail it down.

Clearly, it's because the line is a nested formula, I just can't see to get the parsing right.

Answer (score 1):

- `OR` needs to have atleast two arguments - `OR(I2 = "in progress", I2 = "xyz")`
- `ARRAYFORMULA` does not understand `AND()` and `OR()` that's why you need to convert it to 0/1 logic

try this formula:

**`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I2:I = "in progress"; S2:S+30; I2:I))`**

if you got 2+ arguments for `OR` then try:

**`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((I2:I = "in progress") + (I2:I = "xyz"); S2:S+30; I2:I))`**